# Is it possible to use automapper with nhibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, automapper

I'm using NHibernate (v3.3) to load/save my domain model classes to database. I've created bunch of View Model classes to use on front end of the MVC3 website. So I was planning to use AutoMapper (v2.1) to map view model classes to domain classes.

I've define Map configuration between two classes Restaurant and RestaurantViewModel. Here is the method:

```
    public void Create(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (configuration == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("configuration");

        IMappingExpression<RestaurantViewModel, Restaurant> map =
            configuration.CreateMap<RestaurantViewModel, Restaurant>();

        map.ForMember(x => x.Address, o => o.ResolveUsing(x => new Address
                                                                {
                                                                       BuildingNumber = x.BuildingNumber,
                                                                    City = x.City,
                                                                    PostalCode = x.PostalCode,
                                                                    Street = x.Street
                                                                }));

        map.ForMember(x => x.Categories, o => o.Ignore());
        map.ForMember(x => x.Photo, o => o.Ignore());
    }
```

But I got exception when calling **Mapper.Map<RestaurantViewModel>(restaurant)**;

This is the text of exception:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
RestaurantProxy -> RestaurantViewModel
RestaurantProxy -> FoodDelivery.Website.Models.RestaurantViewModel

Destination path:
RestaurantViewModel

Source value:
FoodDelivery.DataDomain.Restaurant
```

It looks like NHibernate create proxy around my Restaurant with name RestaunrantProxy, so when I ask AutoMapper to map Restaurant to RestaurantViewModel it actually maps Proxy and because there is no Map for that mapper throws an exception.

Are there any ways I can fix the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your error is having problems mapping the `Restaurant` to the `RestaurantViewModel`. Your mapping only appears to cover the mapping in the other direction, view model to entity.

Try adding this?

```
configuration.CreateMap<Restaurant, RestaurantViewModel>();
```

That should allow you to map your Restaurant entity to your view model.

Comment: You are right, I failed to load map Restaurant to RestaurantViewModel properly (marked class with it internal and configuration module didn't find it).
Sorry for disturbing with such stupid question.